# How do I capture the last column with sed?

Tags: sed

I know this is easy with awk (`'{print $NF}'`), but for learning purposes I'd like to understand how to do it with sed.

I have a variable with a bunch of white-space separated values, and I'd like to print just that last one.  I thought I could do it with a greedy match but it's printing everything after the first space, instead of everything after the last space:

```
echo $var
"t1": 0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144
echo $var | sed 's/\S*\(.*\)$/\1/'
0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144
```

When I try putting it in a match group with text afterward, I get even further away:

```
echo $var | sed 's/[\S*.*]+\(.*\)$/\1/'
"t1": 0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144
```

Comment: Try this one-not tested `sed -E 's/.* (.[^\S]*$)/\1/'`

Comment: The issue is that `.` captures everything, including whitespace, so a greedy match from the beginning will work. If you only want non-whitespace characters, you need to specify that. What result do you want, `0.144` or `"t3": 0.144`?

Comment: Do you want to capture the last word, or just print it? `s/.* //` would get you the last word without capturing anything.

Comment: `awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @BenjaminW.- you nailed it, that's all I was looking to do.  I didn't think I even needed the capture group, and I knew it should be incredibly simple.  Post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo ">$var<"
>"t1": 0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144<
$ echo "$var" | sed 's/\S*\(.*\)$/\1/'
 0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144

The regular expression matched as follows:

 \S*
_____
"t1": 0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                  \(.*\)$
```

The [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man7/regex.7.html) specifies that a regex will match *as early as possible*:

> *In  the event that an RE could match more than one substring of a given string, the RE matches the one starting earliest in the string.*

To return only the last substring of non-spaces after the last colon folowed by an optional space use `sed -e 's/.*:\s*//'`:

```
$ echo "$var" | sed -e 's/.*:\s*//'
0.144
```

The regular expression matching like this:

```
             .*                \s*
______________________________ _
"t1": 0.004, "t2": 0.010, "t3": 0.144
                              ^
                              :
```